# This Message Contains Blocked Content, unblocking the app

Tags: facebook, offline, spam

So we wrote an app & integrated it within our service as a feature for users to share their check-ins on their wall (ours is a location based check-in service). Integration runs on SMS (offline token) and Android (SDK integration).

We ran this well for the last 2-3 weeks, but got a 400 response earlier today, with this message
"Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content: Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook users.","type":"OAuthException","code":368"

This has affected our integration on SMS (Android works fine). And we reckon it's because the messages being posted when users shared via SMS were akin i.e. same parameters being passed by a user, very frequently in a day, for essentially performing the same action (of a check in).

So my question, or plea for help really is: what do we need to do to get our app unblocked? who do we need to speak to? and what measures to put in place to ensure this never happens again?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a customer support question.